# delete array item cause error perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

I have google for this problem.
The solution is put is_Mounted in componentWillMount and unmount, but this will let deletion not happened.
I would appreciate it greatly if you could let me know how to deal with this problem which I deal with for about a week.
My pseudocode...

IRPage

```
class IRPage extends Component {
  state = {
    companyList: [],
    contractListOfList: [],
  };

  addCompanyArr = (newCompany) => {
    this.setState(
      state => {
        const list = state.companyList.push(newCompany);
        return {
          list,
        };
      }
    )
  };

  addContractArr = (newContractList) => {
    this.setState(
      state => {
        const list = state.contractListOfList.push(newContractList);
        return {
          list,
        };
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
       // pass array method.....to IRContent 
    )
  }
}
```

IRContent

```
class IRContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    addCompany = () => {
      const companyNode = <IRCompany setContractArr={this.props.setContractArr} contractList={newContractList} companyList={this.props.companyList} setCompanyArr={this.props.setCompanyArr} addContractArr={this.props.addContractArr}/>;
      this.props.addCompanyArr(companyNode);
      var newContractList = [];
      this.props.addContractArr(newContractList);
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            {
              this.props.companyList.map((element, index) => {
                return <div key={"myCompanyKey_"+index+"_"+this.props.companyList.length} id={index}>{element}</div>;
              })
            }
            <button color="primary" onClick = {this.addCompany}>
              add company
            </button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

IRCompany

```
class IRCompany extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    state = {
      contractList: this.props.contractList,
    };

    deleteCompany = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      // var targetID = ; I'm sure this is correct in original code
      this.props.companyList.splice(targetID, 1);
      this.props.contractListOfList.splice(targetID, 1);
      this.props.setCompanyArr();
    };

    addContract = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      var newContract = <IRContract contractList={this.state.contractList} setContractList={this.setContractList} setCompanyArr={this.props.setCompanyArr} contractListOfList={this.props.contractListOfList} setContractArr={this.props.setContractArr}/>;
      this.props.contractList.push(newContract);
      this.setContractList();
    };

    setContractList = () => {
      this.setState(
        state => {
          const list = state.contractList;
          return {
            list,
          };
        }
      )
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            {
            this.state.contractList.map((element, index) => {
                return <tbody key={"myContractKey" + index + "_" +this.state.contractList.length} id={index}>{element}</tbody>;
            })
            }               
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

IRContract

```
class IRContract extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    deleteMainContract = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.contractList.splice(contractNum, 1);
                this.props.setContractList();
    };

    render() {
        return(
          <React.Fragment>
            <button name="deleteMainContract" type="button" onClick={this.deleteMainContract} style={{borderRadius: "6px", fontSize: "16px"}}>delete</button>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

If I click add company, add contract, and delete contract, it will work correctly.
However, if I click add company, add contract, add another company, and delete contract, it will fail.
Error message is "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.", but I never write something like componentWillUnmount.

Comment: Likely not the cause of your issue but I just want to point out that the return value of a `array::push` is the new length of the array, not the array itself. Also, props are immutable, meaning you can't do the array splicing.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I fixed the problem you mentioned, but you are right these are not the cause of my issue lol.

Comment: I see potential logical bugs/errors/flaws. It is an anti-pattern to store passed props from ancestors into local state. You also have "app state" mutators spread across all these components, some of which incorrectly operate on your state. Keep the functions mutating a piece of state with the component owning the state, and ensure they are doing correct state updates. Try consolidating your logic to see if that helps clear up some of the odd behavior.

Comment: thank you, i finally fix the problem!